# Efficient way of blocking / denying nginx connections via IP

Tags: nginx

I would like to filter several different endpoints by IP using nginx. My current solution is to cut and paste the following code for each endpoint:

```
    location /api0 {
        allow 123.45.67.89; 
        allow 98.765.43.21; 
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    location /api1 {
        allow 123.45.67.89; 
        allow 98.765.43.21; 
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    etc
```

Is there a more efficient way of setting up these IP filters? Is it possible to setup a group so I can use that for all the endpoints in the config file?

My main issue here is that sometimes an IP address needs to be changed, which means I have to manually cut & paste the IP and then restart nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those directives in the server block and they will apply to all locations in the server block.

Or, if you don't want the rules in all locations, you can put these lines

```
allow 123.45.67.89; 
allow 98.765.43.21; 
deny all;
```

into a separate file, say `/etc/nginx/allowlist`, and then include the file where necessary:

```
    location /api0 {
        include allowlist;
        ......
    }

    location /api1 {
        include allowlist;
        ......
    }
```

Comment: thank you - how do I load the "allowlist" into nginx?

Comment: @vgoklani with `include <filename>;` statement, as in the example.

Comment: So in the example, "allowlist" really means include </etc/nginx/allowlist>; ? Is there a way to just load the file once and store it as a global variable, which I could then reference in the location block?

Comment: @vgoklani yes, when you use a relative path like `allowlist` it's relative to `/etc/nginx`, so it becomes `/etc/nginx/allowlist`. As for the second question, I believe you cannot save it as a variable, but you can repeat `include` statements to the same file or files. It is, actually, like a global variable, it just inserts contents of the included file and nothing else.

Comment: thanks for the clarification; presumably one could then define multiple files each containing different groups of IP addresses, stack them via successive include <..> statements, and then finally add a single "deny all;" statement at the end.

Comment: @vgoklani yes, that's possible.